# SQL: combining two tables without Cartesian product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine two tables with the same number of rows without doing a full-blown Cartesian product. In a way it's like having two columns of the same length beside each other, no matter the ordering.

To be more specific say I have two tables. Table a:

```
id  fieldA  commonField
1   foo1    value1
2   foo2    value1
3   foo3    value2
4   foo4    value2
```

and table b:

```
id  fieldB  commonField
11  bar1    value1
12  bar2    value1
13  bar3    value2
14  bar4    value2
```

See also the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ffa02/10/0). The result of the query I'm looking for should be:

```
id  fieldA  commonField fieldB
1   foo1    value1  bar1
2   foo2    value1  bar2
3   foo3    value2  bar3
4   foo4    value2  bar4
```

The ordering of the fieldB column within the same value of the commonField is not important.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: @Cetin Basoz It's SQL server

Comment: What is the result if table a has more rows than table b? What is the result if table a has less rows than table b?

Comment: I can guarantee that they have the same number of rows

Comment: If the joining condition is to join the number in TableA - FieldA, with the number in TableB - FieldB- then you need to separate the number out of those fields into it's own column.  Then inner join or sub-query on the matching numbers.  Also, keeping the word plus the number is not an atomic value and a violation of 1NF.

Comment: what is your exception, please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as given below:

```
select t1.id, t1.fieldA,t2.fieldB
from
(SELECT a.*, row_number() OVER (order by commonfield) as rn from a) as t1
join (select fieldB, row_number() OVER (order by commonfield) as rn from b) as t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Doesn't this completely ignore commonField match?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I think the data provided is not complete... OP omits non-matching condition in his question.  This is not a good question IMO.  And I don't understand how either one of your answers extracts the number out of "foo" to match with the same number in  "bar" (assuming that was the intent)?

Comment: @Zorkolot, it doesn't match on foo or bar, just row_number partitioned by commonField.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server:

```
with t1 (rNO, id, fieldA, commonField) as
(
select row_number() over (partition by commonField order by id), id, fieldA, commonField
from a
),
t2 (rNO, id, fieldB, commonField) as
(
select row_number() over (partition by commonField order by id), id, fieldB, commonField
from b
)
select t1.id, t1.fieldA, t1.commonField, t2.fieldB 
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.commonField = t2.commonField and t1.rNo = t2.rNo;
```

PS: Depending on your needs you may be seeking for a full join instead:

```
with t1 (rNO, id, fieldA, commonField) as
(
select row_number() over (partition by commonField order by id), id, fieldA, commonField
from a
),
t2 (rNO, id, fieldB, commonField) as
(
select row_number() over (partition by commonField order by id), id, fieldB, commonField
from b
)
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, t1.fieldA, coalesce(t1.commonField, t2.commonField) as commonField, t2.fieldB 
from t1
full join t2 on t1.commonField = t2.commonField and t1.rNo = t2.rNo;
```